# ¿Como agregar elementos a un ObservableList en JavaFx?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, javafx, combobox, fxml

Actualmente estoy haciendo un formulario donde quiero almacenar el registro de un alumno de cualquier institucion, en ese formulario tengo un ComboBox que es el de "grupo" y en dicho Combo quisiera almacenar informacion de la base de datos sobre dicha tabla.

Modelo de Grupo

```
package Modelo;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity(name="grupo")
public class Grupo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int idGrupo;

    @Column(name="NombreG")
    private String nombre;

    @Column(name="CantidadA")
    private int cantidad;

    @Column(name="Grado")
    private String grado;

    @Column(name="Nivel")
    private float nivel;

    @Column(name="Nota")
    private String nota;

    @Column(name="Fecha")
    private Date fecha;

    @Column(name="IdPeriodo")
    private int id_periodo;


    public Grupo(int idGrupo, String nombre, int cantidad, String grado, float nivel, String nota, Date fecha,
            int id_periodo) {
        super();
        this.idGrupo = idGrupo;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
        this.grado = grado;
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.nivel = nivel;
        this.nota = nota;
        this.id_periodo = id_periodo;
    }

    public Grupo() {
        this(0,"",0,"",0.0f,"",new Date(),0);
    }

    public int getIdGrupo() {
        return idGrupo;
    }

    public void setIdGrupo(int idGrupo) {
        this.idGrupo = idGrupo;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getCantidad() {
        return cantidad;
    }

    public void setCantidad(int cantidad) {
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }

    public String getGrado() {
        return grado;
    }

    public void setGrado(String grado) {
        this.grado = grado;
    }

    public float getNivel() {
        return nivel;
    }

    public void setNivel(float nivel) {
        this.nivel = nivel;
    }

    public String getNota() {
        return nota;
    }

    public void setNota(String nota) {
        this.nota = nota;
    }

    public Date getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public int getId_periodo() {
        return id_periodo;
    }

    public void setId_periodo(int id_periodo) {
        this.id_periodo = id_periodo;
    }



}
```

Controlador de Grupo

```
 @FXML
        private ComboBox<Grupo> cmbGrupo;
        private ObservableList<Grupo> grupos;

cmbGrupo = new ComboBox<>();
        grupos = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        cmbGrupo.setItems(grupos);
```

Al compilar el programa me sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando lo que almacenas en un ComboBox es un tipo propio, necesitas indicarle al ComboBox cómo tiene que mostrarlos. Para ello le tienes que asignar una comboBox.setCellFactory(cellFactory); (ver http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html). Además, también tendrás que asignarle un Converter para indicarle como mostrar la opción seleccionada en la parte de Button. Respecto a tu captura de pantalla y tu código, aparece vacío porque no has añadido ninguna instancia a la lista grupos.

Answer (score 0):

Para agregar elementos al ComboBox debes utilizar el método setItems(...) indicando los elementos que este contendrá, puedes ver un buen ejemplo de como utilizar este control aquí: http://acodigo.blogspot.com/2015/04/javafx-uso-de-combobox.html

Comment: Es mejor incluir ejemplos sencillos o al menos las partes esenciales de la referencia externa ya que esas pueden desaparecer.